# What kind of SQL Join am i looking for? A Join without on

Tags: sql

This may seem a bit elementary, but its my first time i've encounter this join scenario.
I'm trying to join the following tables

**TableA**

```
Apple
Banana
```

**TableB**

```
Blue
Red
```

Results should be:

```
Apple Blue
Apple Red
Banana Blue
Banana Red
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

You need a `cross join`

```
select * from tableA cross join tableB
```

or you can simply `select` from both the tables with out a `join` condition.

```
select * from tableA, tableB
```

Comment: Absolutely!  A cross-join takes the Cartesian product of the two tables, "multiplying" each element in the first set with each element in the second set.

Comment: I'm not use to using cross join but the second solution was what I was about to offer, you beat me to it :P.

Comment: @Pinch.. there would not be..as you are not joining the tables. It would be fast. You would get num rows of A * num rows of B.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a cross join:

```
select a.col1 as col1_a, b.col1 as col1_b
from table_a
  cross join table_b;
```